# Symfony - permissions (rights) instead of roles

Tags: php, symfony-2.3, symfony

I already implemented a user registration/login schema in my Symfony 3.x project. I based my implementation on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html (among others).

Well, it works, but it's based on roles, and now I want to change it to permissions, like: "can_edit", "can_post", "can_delete" etc.

It doesn't work like roles, there is no such thing like "role hierarchy", besides my logic behind controlling user access will be a bit more complicated than just editing security.yml -> access_control.

So how can I accomplish this?

Btw, what I already did is:

Reading this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html :)

Creating tables "permission" and "user_permission". The "permission" table has an id and a "symbol" (text) column (e.g. with a value == "can_post"). Then user_permission has "user_id" and "permission_id" fields.

I also created a "permission" entity (I use ORM), and modified user entity, so it is now joined with "permission":

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Permission", cascade = {"persist"})
 */
private $userPermissions;
```

But I have no idea if I'm this is the way to go? And what to do next? I'm very new to Symfony.

Btw, I don't think I want to use ACL, because of this comment in Symfony's docs:

> Using ACL's isn't trivial, and for simpler use cases, it may be
>   overkill. If your permission logic could be described by just writing
>   some code (e.g. to check if a Blog is owned by the current User), then
>   consider using voters.

Comment: In your case, if you want to deal with permission on specific action, and not in a whole entity / controller, voters may be the best way to deal with

Comment: @Bart Bartoman - OK, will do, thanks!